# Sync v3 SNMP trap and receiver - engineBoot engineTime out of sync

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap

I have configured a v3 SNMP trap and I have confirmed a trap is being received but the following error is appearing:

"RFC3414 §3.2.7.a Not in time window; engineID='', engineBoots=19, engineTime=60374
"

From various articles I can see it is due to the engineBoots and engineTime not being in sync between the sender and receiver of the trap.

Can someone recommend what is the best way to sync the sender and receiver of the trap?

Comment: Who wrote that receiver application? SNMP TRAP's time sync is different from other message types, so what you observed can be a serious bug of that receiver.